# What is the Best approach to run a long process using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like to ask what is the best approach to run a long process using Spring. I have a webapp and when the client does a request it runs a Spring controller. This Controller would get some parameters from the request and then runs a query and fetch records from the DB.

The records from the DB are high, i need to do a comparing logic which may take a long time, so I need to run it separately.
When this process is executed , it should write the final results into an excel file and mail it.

Comment: The Spring documentation has a whole chapter dedicated to asynchronous task execution: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling

Answer (score 6):

You can use the annotation `@Async` to return immediately.

Fisrt, write a `@Service` class to process you DB and Excel job.

```
@Service
public class AccountService {
    @Async
    public void executeTask(){
    // DB and Excel job
    }
}
```

Then, In controller method trigger the task

```
@Controller
public class taskController{
    @RequestMapping(value = "as")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResultInfo async() throws Exception{
        accountService.executeTask();
        return new ResultInfo(0, "success", null);
    }
}
```

At last, add this to application-context.xml(spring config file)

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor"/>
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="10"/>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Also recommend to look at "spring batch" framework for batch processing. It can halving execution time.

Comment: Thanks @Larrry for the response.However I am using spring 2.5.Is there any equivalent mechanism in 2.5 to make asynchronous calls? If not is there any alternative way to make asynchronous service calls ? Please suggest me!

Comment: @The User 518469 - How can Spring Batch reduce the execution time if it is used in comparison to asynchronous call.